# Search not working in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I working with search function in WordPress theme and happen a problem is:
I have a custom post type and custom taxonomy in function. I don't know this affect to search in WordPress or not? Input in form WordPress with `name ="s"`

My query search:

```
 $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged);
        $posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Search is normal working if I remove `$posts = new WP_Query($args);` and in loop not use  `$posts`.
And my naigation is:

```
paginate_links( array(
    'format' => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
    'total' => $posts->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => __('Previous', 'extc'),
    'next_text' => __('Next', 'extc')
) );
```

Comment: This should've been posted to wordpress se

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_search_query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for bro help me. This problem was solved. I try change my query into:

```
$posts = new WP_Query();
$posts = $posts->query('post_type=post&s='.get_search_query().'&posts_per_page=5&paged='.$paged);
```

It's awsome! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

After executing your custom query you need to restore the original post data:

```
 wp_reset_postdata();
```

You are not stating you are doing this and it looks like this is causing you problems by messing up $post variable.

Check it out in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's not working. post not filtering, list post is full.

Comment: Seem to my query incorrect. Because when I remove above code, then it's working.

Comment: Are you resetting the main loop results after your query?

Answer (score 0):

@Mr D I believe you have to include a tax query in your args like so:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'your_custom_taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'your_custom_taxonomy_term',
        )
    )
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

and you also have to declare the taxonomy on your custom post type registration